# How can I build an enum with Dart?

Tags: dart

The Dart language does not have enums (yet??). What is the proper or idiomatic way to construct an enum, at least until a language feature arrives?

Comment: As of Dart 1.8, you can now use formal enums. See accepted answer below.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

With r41815 Dart got native Enum support see http://dartbug.com/21416 and can be used like

```dart
enum Status {
  none,
  running,
  stopped,
  paused
}

void main() {
  print(Status.values);
  Status.values.forEach((v) => print('value: $v, index: ${v.index}'));
  print('running: ${Status.running}, ${Status.running.index}');
  print('running index: ${Status.values[1]}');
}
```

> [Status.none, Status.running, Status.stopped, Status.paused]
>   value: Status.none, index: 0
>   value: Status.running, index: 1
>   value: Status.stopped, index: 2
>   value: Status.paused, index: 3
>   running: Status.running, 1
>   running index: Status.running

A limitation is that it is not possibly to set custom values for an enum item, they are automatically numbered.

More details at in this draft https://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/EnumsTC52draft.pdf

Answer (score 79):

**Dart now has support for enums**.

The rest of this answer is for Dart <= 1.8. If using > 1.8, use Dart's formal support for enums (explained in another answer).

It's true, the Dart language does not (yet?) have enums. There is an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=88) for it.

In the meantime, here is an idiomatic Dart snippet to create your own enum.

```dart
class Enum {
  final _value;
  const Enum._internal(this._value);
  toString() => 'Enum.$_value';

  static const FOO = const Enum._internal('FOO');
  static const BAR = const Enum._internal('BAR');
  static const BAZ = const Enum._internal('BAZ');
}
```

Using const constructors means you can use this enum in a switch. Here's an example:

```dart
class Fruits {
  final _value;
  const Fruits._internal(this._value);
  toString() => 'Enum.$_value';

  static const APPLE = const Fruits._internal('APPLE');
  static const PEAR = const Fruits._internal('PEAR');
  static const BANANA = const Fruits._internal('BANANA');
}

void main() {
  var yummy = Fruits.BANANA;

  switch (yummy) {
    case Fruits.APPLE:
      print('an apple a day');
      break;
    case Fruits.PEAR:
      print('genus Pyrus in the family Rosaceae');
      break;
    case Fruits.BANANA:
      print('open from the bottom, it is easier');
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Small warning: it is a common error to create a const object without any value. For example "class Enum { const Enum(); }". This wouldn't work because Dart canonicalizes constant objects. So always make sure to have a value that differentiates the individual enum-values.

Comment: yummy =='BANANA' returns *false*...
What a shame... :/

Comment: Dart has now experimental support for enums: http://news.dartlang.org/2014/11/dart-18-library-improvements-and.html

Comment: @AnthonyBobenrieth Yeah. But you can do yummy.value == 'BANANA' if you add a getter for _value.

Comment: Is it possible to add a `fromString(String)` constructor? I tried adding a `const factory Fruits.fromString(String s) = _internal;` but it seems to create instances that are not equal to `APPLE`, `PEAR` and `BANANA`...

Comment: @MagnusW You would need to override the `==` operator and the `hashCode` getter assuming you would be using `==` for comparison. If that doesn't work for you I don't see an easy way to get the actual static const instances.

Answer (score 18):

I use a little bit simpler version of the Enum class in [Dart Web Toolkit](http://www.dartwebtoolkit.com):

```dart
/**
 * Emulation of Java Enum class.
 *
 * Example:
 *
 * class Meter<int> extends Enum<int> {
 *
 *  const Meter(int val) : super (val);
 *
 *  static const Meter HIGH = const Meter(100);
 *  static const Meter MIDDLE = const Meter(50);
 *  static const Meter LOW = const Meter(10);
 * }
 *
 * and usage:
 *
 * assert (Meter.HIGH, 100);
 * assert (Meter.HIGH is Meter);
 */
abstract class Enum<T> {

  final T _value;

  const Enum(this._value);

  T get value => _value;
}
```

Comment: I like top-level constants for my enums. You can use imports to fix any collisions. This makes using the enums much less verbose. Edit - added an example.

Comment: Is it ok to add an method:
toString() => value;
?

Answer (score 5):

I like top-level constants for my enums. You can use imports to fix any collisions. This makes using the enums much less verbose.

i.e.

```dart
if (m == high) {}
```

instead of:

```dart
if (m == Meter.high) {}
```

Enum definition:

```dart
class Meter<int> extends Enum<int> {
   const Meter(int val) : super (val);
}

const Meter high = const Meter(100);
const Meter middle = const Meter(50);
const Meter low = const Meter(10);
```

Comment: is this a good idea? I feel like using imports to clear out polluted namespace is not the way to go in a large project