# Why is it possible to have a non static const variable in a non static method inside a Class

Tags: dart, constants

I get that const variables inside classes must be static, because the Compiler cant access them at Compile time.
But why can I then have a non static Method inside this class which contains a non static const, shouldn´t be then also nonaccessible at Compile time?

```
class ImmutablePoint {

  void someNonStaticMethod(){
    const v = 3;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I get that const variables inside classes must be static, because the Compiler cant access them at Compile time-

The *compiler* can access whatever it wants.  It has access to all of your source code, after all.

`const` members are required to be `static` to emphasize that `const` objects are *shared* and aren't duplicated across instances. ([It also wasn't always the case that `const` class members required `static`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17075028/179715).)

Comment: But what would be so bad to have duplicates?

Comment: One of the main reasons to use `const` is to have a single, canonical, shared instance used throughout your program.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help, but wouldnt it make also sense then to make all methods in such a class static

Comment: No, it would not make sense.  `const` objects are shared instances, but each instance can still have its own data.  Suppose you have `const ImmutablePoint(1, 1)` and `const ImmutablePoint(2, 3)` objects.  It does not make sense for `ImmutablePoint` to have `static` `x` and `y` members.  It also would not make sense to have, say, a `static` `distanceFromOrigin()` method.