# Why we use the static statement in this user model file with Equatable package? And why we are passing a 'blank' argument for User

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

Why static keyword is used? Why passing a '-' argument for User?

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class User extends Equatable {
  const User(this.id);

  final String id;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [id];

  *static const empty = User('-');*
}
```

Comment: Did you ask the person who wrote this? It's a choice this person made. We cannot say why a minus was chosen. What connection does flutter-bloc have to this code?

Comment: It's `static` because it's `const` ([`const` members must be `static`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17074897/)).

Comment: What happens if you remove the line? If something does not work any longer, it may give you a hint what this is used for. If everything works when removing that line, it probably wasn't really important and is indeed not useful for your program.

Comment: This snippet is from the flutter_login example written by the Author of the bloc library itself!

Comment: A possible motivation: declaring `empty` as **`static const`**, it is possible to use `empty` as **default value for a named parameter**. For example: `void logIn({User user = User.empty}) {}`. However, the use of '-' for the `id` is an arbitrary choice.

Comment: It is not related to the subclassing of Equatable (which serves to provide the class of an implementation of `hashCode` and `==`)