# Dart How to get the name of an enum as a String

Tags: enums, dart

Before enums were available in Dart I wrote some cumbersome and hard to maintain code to simulate enums and now want to simplify it.  I need to get the name of the enum as a string such as can be done with Java but cannot.

For instance little test code snippet returns 'day.MONDAY' in each case when what I want is 'MONDAY"

```
enum day {MONDAY, TUESDAY}
print( 'Today is $day.MONDAY');
print( 'Today is $day.MONDAY.toString()');
```

Am I correct that to get just 'MONDAY' I will need to parse the string?

Comment: And there is no iterator?

Comment: Dart provide method for get value describeEnum, see example https://stackoverflow.com/a/60615370/11827756

Comment: Dart needs something like a 'name' built-in property to curtail all this foolishness (e.g., day.MONDAY.name).

Comment: This is https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1511.

Comment: it actually has this now: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/describeEnum.html

Answer (score 106, accepted):

It used to be correct that the only way to get the source name
of the enum value was through the `toString` method which returns `"day.MONDAY"`, and not the more useful `"MONDAY"`.

Since Dart 2.15, enums have exposed a extension getter which returns just the source name, so `day.MONDAY.name == "MONDAY"`.

Since Dart 2.17, you can also add your own members to `enum` declarations, and choose to provide another name for
a value than justits source name, e.g., with a more appropriate capitalization:

```dart
enum Day {
  monday("Monday"),
  tuesday("Tuesday"),
  // ...
  saturday("Saturday");
  sunday("Sunday");
 
  final String name;
  Day(this.name);
 
  // And other members too.
  bool get isWorkday => index < saturday.index;
}
```

Then you get `Day.sunday.name == "Sunday"` (hiding the extension `name` getter which would return "sunday").

Before these features, you could only get the name from the `toString` string, extracting the rest of the string as:

```dart
day theDay = day.MONDAY;      
print(theDay.toString().substring(theDay.toString().indexOf('.') + 1));
```

which was admittedly hardly convenient.

Another way to get the enum name as a string, one which is shorter, but also less efficient because it creates an unnecessary string for first part of the string too, was:

```dart
theDay.toString().split('.').last
```

If performance doesn't matter, that's probably what I'd write, just for brevity.

If you want to iterate all the values, you can do it using `day.values`:

```dart
for (day theDay in day.values) {
  print(theDay);
}
```

Comment: The old way enums http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854549 offer more flexibility but can't be used as constants. Creating a library and importing it with a prefix allows to work around this (see this answer in the lined question above http://stackoverflow.com/a/15855913/217408).

Comment: What is the problem with using "enum-class" instances as constants?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem creating const instances of a class and having them available as static const members - that's what the language enum implementation does anyway: `class MyEnum { static const MyEnum someItem = const MyEnum(0); static const MyEnum someOtherItem = const MyEnum(1); final int id; const MyEnum(this.id); }`

Comment: @Irm I was able to to rewrite and test a couple of methods I need.  Perhaps enum will be extended some day to provide the name as a string.

Comment: @lrn I tried it and it worked. Thanks for pointing that out. The last time I tried I got an error at `doSomething1([Status status = Status.off]) {` [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/59f4ff738632009278d4)

Comment: @Irn To me this code to parse the string returned by toString() is more readable: unumName(var target) => (target.toString()).split('.')[1]; Is it equivalent or a bad practice? I'm still pretty much a novice with Dart.

Comment: Using `split` is slightly more wasteful because it creates two substrings and only uses one of them.  If it's not used heavily, it's probably just the same.

Comment: Had the same problem in one of my projects and existing solutions were not very clean, I published my code `Vnum` in pub package. Hope it helps someone.
https://github.com/AmirKamali/Flutter_Vnum

Comment: This answer is outdated, as many have stated, .name (e.g. day.monday.name) is the way to go since Dart 2.15.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, will update answer.

Answer (score 241):

**Dart 2.15**

```
enum Day { monday, tuesday }

main() {
  Day monday = Day.monday;
  print(monday.name); //prints 'monday'
}
```

**Dart 2.7 - 2.14**

With new feature called [Extension methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) you can write your own methods for Enum as simple as that!

```
enum Day { monday, tuesday }

extension ParseToString on Day {
  String toShortString() {
    return this.toString().split('.').last;
  }
}

main() {
  Day monday = Day.monday;
  print(monday.toShortString()); //prints 'monday'
}
```

Comment: As described here, I couldn't use the extension from a different file although the enum was correctly imported. It worked when I followed doc example and added a name to the extension: "extension Formatting on Day". Maybe have an edit if it's not just me. Also response should be updated with a mix of Jannie and mbartn responses.

Comment: I reverted last edit changes because it doesn't work without name of extension

Comment: this is not the best solution. Kalpesh Dabhi providade a better one here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60615370/9695154

Comment: `describeEnum` is a Flutter only method, the question is hot to get the value of an enum in Dart

Comment: @mbartn Flutter's implementation shown at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/describeEnum.html

Comment: To prevent attacks / collisions via 3rd party libs, the extension works only in the local file. To use it in other files you will have to import the extension name itself, in this case: `ParseToString`. Keep in mind that if you need i18n then using enums as string might not be the best approach. Some "intermediary" code will still be needed.

Answer (score 151):

#### Update Dart 2.15:

```dart
enum Day {
  monday,
  tuesday,
}
```

You can use `name` property on the enum.

```dart
String monday = Day.monday.name; // 'monday'
```

---

#### Old solution:

**1. Direct way:**

```dart
var dayInString = describeEnum(Day.monday);
print(dayInString); // prints 'monday'
```

---

**2. Using Extension:**

```dart
extension DayEx on Day {
  String get name => describeEnum(this);
}
```

You can use it like:

```dart
void main() {
  Day monday = Day.monday;
  print(monday.name); // 'monday'
}
```

Comment: Taking advantage of `describeEnum` is the way to go. Using an extension is a neat bonus

Comment: Worth noting that `describeEnum` is a method only available through the Flutter framework. So not ideal for those who want to do the same in vanilla dart.

Comment: This should be the first answer (current first answer is obsolete).

Comment: what if I have the `.name` and want to get back enum value ?

Answer (score 140):

Bit shorter:

```
String day = theDay.toString().split('.').last;
```

Comment: simpler way: theDay.toString().split('.').last

Comment: Thanks, @Hani! Your improvement is both simpler and "safer". Updated the answer.

Answer (score 82):

Simplest way to get the name of an enum is a standard method from the flutter/foundation.dart

```
describeEnum(enumObject)

enum Day {
  monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday
}

void validateDescribeEnum() {
  assert(Day.monday.toString() == 'Day.monday');
  assert(describeEnum(Day.monday) == 'monday');
}
```

Comment: This can only be used in Flutter. For dart only code (run with dart instead of flutter), it will cause an error.

Comment: The full implementation is given at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/describeEnum.html

Comment: check this post, it will solve all the problems https://arkapp.medium.com/supercharge-enum-with-extensions-in-flutter-abf8fdf706fe

Answer (score 24):

```
enum day {MONDAY, TUESDAY}
print( 'Today is ${describeEnum(day.MONDAY)}' );
```

console output: Today is MONDAY

Answer (score 23):

There is a more elegant solution:

```
enum SomeStatus {
  element1,
  element2,
  element3,
  element4,
}

const Map<SomeStatus, String> SomeStatusName = {
  SomeStatus.element1: "Element 1",
  SomeStatus.element2: "Element 2",
  SomeStatus.element3: "Element 3",
  SomeStatus.element4: "Element 4",
};

print(SomeStatusName[SomeStatus.element2]) // prints: "Element 2"
```

Comment: Are you calling it elegant? How? By adding extra space into memory and 20 new lines?

Comment: this is actually an anti-pattern. when you need to add more values to your enum, you need to modify the code at two places because you should modify the map as well. imagine if you have hundreds of enums in a big app and hundreds of maps for them at different parts of the app. quite hard to maintain.

Comment: I actually really like this. The other solutions seem hacky.

Comment: If you are using JsonSerializable this Map can be generated automatically by it. And since most real world projects need to use some kind of JSON parser I see this as the best solution. Others rely on implementation detail of enum.toString() having a dot in it.

Comment: Now dart has `enum.name` there is no reason to use this pattern.

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes I need to separate ui-value and real-value, so I defined keys and values using `Map`. This way, we have more flexiblity. And by using `extension` (since Dart 2.7), I made a method to read its key and value.

```
enum Status {
  progess,
  done,
}

extension StatusExt on Status {
  static const Map<Status, String> keys = {
    Status.progess: 'progess',
    Status.done: 'done',
  };

  static const Map<Status, String> values = {
    Status.progess: 'In Progress',
    Status.done: 'Well done',
  };

  String get key => keys[this];
  String get value => values[this];

  // NEW
  static Status fromRaw(String raw) => keys.entries
      .firstWhere((e) => e.value == raw, orElse: () => null)
      ?.key;
}

// usage 1
Status status = Status.done;
String statusKey = status.key; // done
String statusValue = status.value; // Well done

// usage 2 (easy to make key and value list)
List<Status> statuses = Status.values;
List<String> statusKeys = statuses.map((e) => e.key).toList();
List<String> statusValues = statuses.map((e) => e.value).toList();

// usage 3. create Status enum from string.
Status done1 = StatusExt.fromRaw('done') // Status.done
Status done2 = StatusExt.fromRaw('dude') // null
```

Answer (score 12):

As noted in https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-17-b216bfc80c5d:

> With **Dart 2.17** we now have general support for members on enums.
> That means we can add fields holding state, constructors that set that
> state, methods with functionality, and even override existing members.

Example:

```
enum Day {
   MONDAY("Monday"),
   TUESDAY("Tuesday");

  const Day(this.text);
  final String text;
}
```

**Output:**

```
void main() {
  const day = Day.MONDAY;
  print(day.text); /// Monday
}
```

For above functionality override dart version like below which target 2.17 and greater

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.0 <3.0.0"
```

Comment: Its working, but there is a mistake need be corrected enum Day {
   MONDAY("Monday"),
   TUESDAY("Tuesday");

  const Day(this.text);
  final String text;
}

Answer (score 9):

I use structure like below:

```
abstract class Strings {
  static const angry = "Dammit!";
  static const happy = "Yay!";
  static const sad = "QQ";
}
```

Comment: Use `abstract` to make it not initiatable as there's no reason you want to instantiate this class

Comment: How would you use this in a dropdown widget or anything widget?

Answer (score 8):

I use the functions below to get the name of the enum value and, vise versa, the enum value by the name:

```dart
String enumValueToString(Object o) => o.toString().split('.').last;

T enumValueFromString<T>(String key, Iterable<T> values) => values.firstWhere(
      (v) => v != null && key == enumValueToString(v),
      orElse: () => null,
    );
```

When using Dart 2.7 and newer, extension methods would work here (as well as for any other Objects):

```dart
extension EnumX on Object {
  String asString() => toString().split('.').last;
}
```

The implementation above is not dependant on the specific enums.

Usage examples:

```dart
enum Fruits {avocado, banana, orange}
...
final banana = enumValueFromString('banana', Fruits.values);
print(enumValueToString(banana)); // prints: "banana"
print(banana.asString()); // prints: "banana"
```

*Edit from 2020-04-05:* Added nullability checks. `values` parameter could be `Iterable`, not necessarily `List`. Added extensions method implementation. Removed `<Fruits>` annotation from the example to show that the class name duplication is not required.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Alexandr! This was exactly what I was looking for in my case ;-)

Comment: best  answer for deal enum

Answer (score 8):

I got so over this I made a package:

https://pub.dev/packages/enum_to_string

Also has a handy function that takes `enum.ValueOne` and parses it to "`Value one`"

Its a simple little library but its unit tested and I welcome any additions for edge cases.

Answer (score 7):

Dart 2.15 includes an extension to make this easy:

```
enum day {MONDAY, TUESDAY}
print( 'Today is ${day.MONDAY.name}');
```

Until the changes in https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/commit/18f37dd8f3db6486f785b2c42a48dfa82de0948b are rolled out to a stable version of Dart, the other clever but more complex answers here are very useful.

Answer (score 6):

since dart 2.15 just use ".name"

```
enum day {monday, tuesday}
print( 'Today is ${day.monday.name}');
```

Comment: They finally did it!

Answer (score 4):

One more way:

```
enum Length {
  TEN,
  TWENTY,
  THIRTY,
  NONE,
}

extension LengthValue on Length {
  static const _values = [10, 20, 30, 0];

  int get value => _values[this.index];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My approach is not fundamentally different, but might be slightly more convenient in some cases:

```
enum Day {
  monday,
  tuesday,
}

String dayToString(Day d) {
  return '$d'.split('.').last;
}
```

In Dart, you cannot customize an enum's `toString` method, so I think this helper function workaround is necessary and it's one of the best approaches. If you wanted to be more correct in this case, you could make the first letter of the returned string uppercase.

You could also add a `dayFromString` function

```
Day dayFromString(String s) {
  return Day.values.firstWhere((v) => dayToString(v) == s);
}
```

Example usage:

```
void main() {
  Day today = Day.monday;
  print('Today is: ${dayToString(today)}');
  Day tomorrow = dayFromString("tuesday");
  print(tomorrow is Day);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
enum day {MONDAY, TUESDAY}
print(day.toString().split('.')[1]);
OR
print(day.toString().split('.').last);
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a class to help:

```
class Enum {
    Enum._();

    static String name(value) {
        return value.toString().split('.').last;
    }
}
```

and call:

```
Enum.name(myEnumValue);
```

Comment: What does the class add that a normal method would not achieve?

Answer (score 3):

One of the good ways I found in the answer is

```
String day = theDay.toString().split('.').last;
```

##### But I would not suggest doing this as dart provide us a better way.

Define an extension for the enum, may be in the same file as:

```
enum Day {
  monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday
}

extension DayExtension on Day {
  String get value => describeEnum(this);
}
```

You need to do `import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';` for this.

Answer (score 3):

As from Dart 2.15, you can get enum value from

```
print(MyEnum.one.name);
// and for getting enum from value you use
print(MyEnum.values.byName('two');
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in one of my projects and existing solutions were not very clean and it didn't support advanced features like json serialization/deserialization.

Flutter natively doesn't currently support enum with values, however, I managed to develop a helper package `Vnum` using class and reflectors implementation to overcome this issue.

Address to the repository:

https://github.com/AmirKamali/Flutter_Vnum

To answer your problem using `Vnum`, you could implement your code as below:

```
@VnumDefinition
class Visibility extends Vnum<String> {
  static const VISIBLE = const Visibility.define("VISIBLE");
  static const COLLAPSED = const Visibility.define("COLLAPSED");
  static const HIDDEN = const Visibility.define("HIDDEN");

  const Visibility.define(String fromValue) : super.define(fromValue);
  factory Visibility(String value) => Vnum.fromValue(value,Visibility);
}
```

You can use it like :

```
var visibility = Visibility('COLLAPSED');
print(visibility.value);
```

There's more documentation in the github repo, hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of defining extension for every enum, we can define extension on object and get access to `.enumValue` from any enum.

```
void main() {

  // ❌ Without Extension ❌

  print(Countries.Cote_d_Ivoire.toString().split('.').last.replaceAll("_", " ")); // Cote d Ivoire
  print(Movies.Romance.toString().split('.').last.replaceAll("_", " ")); //Romance


  // ✅ With Extension ✅

  print(Countries.Cote_d_Ivoire.enumValue); // Cote d Ivoire
  print(Movies.Romance.enumValue); //Romance
}

enum Countries { United_States, United_Kingdom, Germany, Japan, Cote_d_Ivoire }
enum Movies { Romance, Science_Fiction, Romantic_Comedy, Martial_arts }

extension PrettyEnum on Object {
  String get enumValue => this.toString().split('.').last.replaceAll("_", " ");
}
```

With this, you can even define multi-word enum where words are separated by `_`(underscore) in its name.

Answer (score 2):

For those who require enum with values use this approach as Dart doesn't support this:

```
class MyEnumClass {
  static String get KEY_1 => 'value 1';
  static String get KEY_2 => 'value 2';
  static String get KEY_3 => 'value 3';
  ...
}

// Usage:
print(MyEnumClass.KEY_1); // value 1
print(MyEnumClass.KEY_2); // value 2
print(MyEnumClass.KEY_3); // value 3
...
```

And sure you may put whatever types you need.

Answer (score 1):

**try this solution:**

```
extension EnumValueToString on Enum {
  String valueAsString() {
    return describeEnum(this);
  }
}
```

how to used it:

```
enum.valueAsString()
```

Answer (score 1):

dart 2.15 is now supporting this
you can just type

```
print(day.MONDAY.name); //gives you: MONDAY
```

Comment: that is the up-to-date, proper answer

Answer (score 1):

Since Dart 2.15, we can just do `Day.monday.name`, where

```dart
enum Day { monday, tuesday }
```

Answer (score 1):

As from Dart version 2.15, you can access the `String` value of an `enum` constant using `.name`:

```dart
enum day {MONDAY, TUESDAY}

void main() {
  print('Today is ${day.MONDAY.name}');
  // Outputs: Today is MONDAY
}
```

You can read in detail about all the `enum` improvements in the official Dart 2.15 release [blog post](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-15-7e7a598e508a).

Answer (score 1):

as of dart 2.15 you can use `.name` to get the name of enum elements.

```
enum day {MONDAY, TUESDAY}
print(day.MONDAY.name); // prints MONDAY
```

Answer (score 1):

Dart version `2.15` has introduced `name` property on enums.

Example

```
void main() {
  MyEnum.values.forEach((e) => print(e.name));
}

enum MyEnum { value1, Value2, VALUE2 }
```

Output:

```
value1
Value2
VALUE2
```

Answer (score 0):

now with null safety it looks like this

```
String enumToString(Object? o) => o != null ? o.toString().split('.').last : '';


T? enumFromString<T>(String key, List<T> values) {
  try {
    return values.firstWhere((v) => key == enumToString(v));
  } catch(e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this package [enum_object](https://pub.dev/packages/enum_object)

````
// convert enum value to string
print(TestEnum.test.enumValue);

// convert String to enum value
var enumObject = EnumObject<TestEnum>(TestEnum.values);
print(enumObject.enumFromString('test2'));```
````

Comment: As from Dart 2.15, you can get enum value from; 
`print(MyEnum.one.name);`
and for getting enum from value you use;
`print(MyEnum.values.byName('two')`

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
 print( 'Today is ${day.MONDAY.name}');
   }
enum day {MONDAY, TUESDAY}
```

Comment: We can use the name function to view only the value of enum as string

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?