# Is there a reason my enum is becoming null in a class constructor?

Tags: enums, dart, flutter

I am including an enum in a `User` class constructor. That field in the class becomes null in the new instance.

I directly set the enum value. I print the class field afterward. It is null.

```
enum Genders {
  MALE,
  FEMALE,
  OTHER
}

class User extends SharedUser {
  User(
      String firstName,
      Genders gender,
  ) : super (firstName: firstName);

  Genders gender;
}

final User user = User(
    'Bob',
    Genders.OTHER
);
print(user.firstName); // Bob
print(user.gender); // null
```

Expected: user.gender would print as Genders.OTHER

Actual: user.gender prints as null

Comment: enums are not pluralized.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29567236

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dart doesn't magically assign parameters constructor to the class fields. You have to specify such behavior yourself.

As such, your User constructor should become:

```
User(String firstName, this.gender): super(firstName: firstName);
```