# Encode Map with Enum to JSON

Tags: json, flutter, dart, serialization

I want to encode my Map to a json. It looks like this:

```
Map<MyEnum, int> map = {type: limit};
```

Where `MyEnum` is an enum. A simple `json.encode(map)` won't work as it does not know how to serialize the enum class I guess.

The error message is:

```
Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: _LinkedHashMap len:1
```

How can I manage to serialize this map to a json?

Comment: What should the `enum` be translated to?

Comment: @julemand101 best case into string and with decode back to the enum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an extension on your enum to convert it to a String then convert your map to a `Map<String, int>` so it will be encoded correctly:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

enum MyEnum { type }

extension MyEnumModifier on MyEnum {
  String get string => this.toString().split('.').last;
}

void main() {
  Map<MyEnum, int> map = {MyEnum.type: 10};
  Map<String, int> newMap = {};
  
  map.forEach((key, value) =>
    newMap[key.string] = value);
  
  final json = jsonEncode(newMap);
  print(json);
}
```

**Output**

```
{"type":10}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use describeEnum method inside foundation.dart

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56313689/12474395)

Answer (score 1):

**This is really not a solution I would recommend but I ended up doing it mostly for "fun". I don't guarantee anything about the solution besides the fact that it is horrible. :)**

The problem is that `enum` is not defined as a valid type for Json so the whole concept does give us some problems. One solution is to translate `enum` values into `String` with the name of the enum first, and then the name of value like `MyFirstEnum.first1`. This representation is what Dart gives you if calling `toString()` on a `enum` value.

This is fine but for safety we could also add a magic string in the beginning like `DART_ENUM:MyFirstEnum.first1` so it is easier to recognize between other strings which could have the same name as the `enum` value without being an enum.

Next is type safety. In Json, we know that all maps has `String` as the type of keys. By making our own representation of `enum` and allowing it to also be keys, we cannot expect a decoder to return e.g. `Map<String, dynamic>` but must return `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`.

With that said, here is my attempt to build a Json decoder and encoder which handles `enum` values. It also works for `enum` keys in maps:

```
import 'dart:convert';

class JsonConverterWithEnumSupport {
  final String magicString;
  final Set<Object> allEnumValues = {};
  final Map<String, Object> enumStringToEnumValue = {};

  JsonConverterWithEnumSupport(List<List<Object>>? enumsValues,
      {this.magicString = "DART_ENUM:"}) {
    enumsValues?.forEach(addEnumValues);
  }

  void addEnumValues(List<Object> enumValues) {
    for (final enumValue in enumValues) {
      enumStringToEnumValue[enumValue.toString()] = enumValue;
      allEnumValues.add(enumValue);
    }
  }

  String _addMagic(dynamic enumValue) => '$magicString$enumValue';
  String _removeMagic(String string) => string.substring(magicString.length);

  String encode(Object? value) =>
      json.encode(value, toEncodable: (dynamic object) {
        if (object is Map) {
          return object.map<dynamic, dynamic>((dynamic key, dynamic value) =>
              MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>(
                  allEnumValues.contains(key) ? _addMagic(key) : key,
                  allEnumValues.contains(value) ? _addMagic(value) : value));
        }

        if (object is List) {
          return object.map<dynamic>(
              (dynamic e) => allEnumValues.contains(e) ? _addMagic(e) : e);
        }

        if (allEnumValues.contains(object)) {
          return _addMagic(object);
        }

        return object;
      });

  dynamic decode(String source) => json.decode(source, reviver: (key, value) {
        if (value is String && value.startsWith(magicString)) {
          return enumStringToEnumValue[_removeMagic(value)];
        }

        if (value is Map) {
          return value.map<dynamic, dynamic>((dynamic key, dynamic value) =>
              MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>(
                  (key is String) && key.startsWith(magicString)
                      ? enumStringToEnumValue[_removeMagic(key)]
                      : key,
                  value));
        }

        return value;
      });
}

enum MyFirstEnum { first1, first2 }
enum MySecondEnum { second1, second2 }

void main() {
  final converter =
      JsonConverterWithEnumSupport([MyFirstEnum.values, MySecondEnum.values]);

  final jsonString = converter.encode({
    MyFirstEnum.first1: [MySecondEnum.second2, MySecondEnum.second1],
    'test': {MyFirstEnum.first2: 5}
  });

  print(jsonString);
  // {"DART_ENUM:MyFirstEnum.first1":["DART_ENUM:MySecondEnum.second2","DART_ENUM:MySecondEnum.second1"],"test":{"DART_ENUM:MyFirstEnum.first2":5}}
  print(converter.decode(jsonString));
  // {MyFirstEnum.first1: [MySecondEnum.second2, MySecondEnum.second1], test: {MyFirstEnum.first2: 5}}
}
```

You will need to feed into `JsonConverterWithEnumSupport` all the possible `enum` values there is possible (see the `main` method in the bottom for example).

If you don't want the magic string to be appended on each `enum` you can just create `JsonConverterWithEnumSupport` with: `magicString: ''` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you will need a function to convert string to enum:

```
T enumFromString<T>(List<T> values, String value) {
  return values.firstWhere((v) => v.toString().split('.')[1] == value, orElse: () => null);
}
```

your enum is

```
enum MyEnum {type, destype};
```

suppose it is used as map inside a class to serialize and deserialize:

```
class MyClass {
  Map<MyEnum, int> myProperty = {type: 1}; 

  // serialize
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'myProperty': myProperty.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key.name, value)),
    }

  // deserialize
  MyClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    myProperty=
        json['myProperty'].map((k, v) => MapEntry(enumFromString<MyEnum>(MyEnum.values, k), v)).cast<MyEnum, int>();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly define enum and value extension

```
enum OrderState { pending, filled, triggered, cancelled }

extension OrderStateExt on OrderState {
  String get value {
    switch (this) {
      case OrderState.pending:
        return "PENDING";
      case OrderState.filled:
        return "FILLED";
      case OrderState.triggered:
        return "TRIGGERED";
      case OrderState.cancelled:
        return "CANCELLED";
    }
  }
}
```

2. model class

```
class OrderRequest {
 OrderState state;
 OrderRequest({required this.state});

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {     
      'state': state.value,    
    };
  }
}

String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

factory OrderRequest.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return OrderRequest (     
      state: OrderState.values
          .where((e) => e.value == map['state']).first      
    );
  } 
 factory OrderRequest.fromJson(String source) =>
      OrderRequest.fromMap(json.decode(source));
```