# How to print value of an enum?

Tags: dart

```
enum Move { rock, paper, scissors }

void main() {
var playerMove = Move.rock;

print(playerMove);

}
```

console will print Move.rock
How can I just print rock without the "Move" ?

Comment: yes, sort of, but the code is long. is there a shorter way to do it?

Comment: Amongst those answers is https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/describeEnum.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64165805/1085699