# Convert enum to List<String>

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

I have enum class and I want to show the enum data to ListView.
Can anyone tell how to do that?

```dart
enum TableType { circle, square, rectangle }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dart How to get the name of an enum as a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567236/dart-how-to-get-the-name-of-an-enum-as-a-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possible duplicate [of this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29567236/10157127)

You can do

```dart
List<String> values = TableType.values.map((e) => e.name).toList();
```

More about [name extension](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/EnumName/name.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like this to be able to use enum values inside your UI:

```
enum TableType { circle, square, rectangle }

class ExmaplePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: TableType.values
          .map(
            (tt) => _Table(tt),
          )
          .toList(
            growable: false,
          ),
    );
  }
}

class _Table extends StatelessWidget {
  final TableType type;
  _Table(this.type);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      type.name,
    );
  }
}
```

But it would be great if you could provide more information about problem you are trying to solve or even provide code example that you tried to use.