# Can I have another form of an enum value?

Tags: dart

I have an enum in client code describing a list of endpoints in the API:

enum Requests {
    GetUsers,
    GetProducts,
    ...
}

I want to send requests to server having these values, like `connection.sendRequest(Requests.GetUsers)`.

Now, in the `sendRequest()` function I want the enum value to be converted to something like `'/users'`.

Can I attach methods to each enum similar to this below?

```
enum Requests {
    GetUsers.toString: '/users',
    GetPendingDomains: '/prodcuts'
}
```

Comment: Perhaps old-style enums like shown in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15854550/217408 are better for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly in the enum ([enums are really basic in Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#enumerated-types)). You have to create a `Map<Requests, String>` aside to handle the associated paths.

```dart
enum Request { GetUsers, GetProducts, ... }
final paths = <Request, String>{
  Request.GetUsers:    '/users',
  Request.GetProducts: '/products',
}
```